# Set label from a nodes property

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How can i add a label for a node from one of the nodes properties ?
I have a large CSV-file with a label in one column. With the LOAD CSV command its not possible to set a nodes label from a CSV-column value.
Is there anoter way ?

Comment: You need the `apoc.create.addLabels` procedure from the APOC-library: https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_creating_data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **APOC** procedures Neo4j plugin contains some useful procedures for helping to refactor a graph (https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_graph_refactorings)

For your needs, you can use the following procedure :

```
CALL apoc.create.addLabels( node, [ properties ] )
```

Here an example :

```
MATCH (n:Movie)
CALL apoc.create.addLabels( id(n), [ n.genre ] ) YIELD node
REMOVE node.genre
RETURN node
```

For installing APOC extension, download the .jar file regarding your Neo4j version, place it into */plugins* folder in your Neo4j installation, then restarts Neo4j.

Comment: Is it possible to create an edge with the given node? Also, how to create only distinct ones?